# texture not loading properly in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to test obj loading and texturing with three.js. I have a very simple file to load a small simple obj and texture it a yellow image with stars on it. I placed a cube next to it and the cube works just fine, but when I run the code, the yellow stars are not on my obj, it is just plain yelllow. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot of the result when I run it]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>
        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.01,10);
            camera.position.z = 5;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
            camera.add( pointLight );
            scene.add( camera );

            var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var map = textureLoader.load('color.png');
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.load( 'lame.obj', function ( obj ) {
                var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( obj );
                var center = new THREE.Vector3();
                box.getCenter( center );
                obj.position.sub( center );
                obj.traverse( function ( node ) {
                if ( node.isMesh ) node.material = material;
                } );
                scene.add( obj );
            },
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
            });

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
                    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    scene.add( cube );
                    cube.position.x=3

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: just a guess that your object has no UV/texture coordinates. Look inside the .obj file. Do you see any lines that start with `vt`?

Comment: no, it just says v, vn and f

Comment: that very easily could be the problem, but I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: That object has no data for how to apply a texture. Re-export it with texture data if you have the original. Otherwise you'll have to make the data yourself. Usually in some tool like [Blender](https://blender.org).

Comment: I will try getting blender and opening my file in there and then exporting it as obj with uv maps, because before I was using paint 3d and then converting it to obj online with a convert site, so that could be why.

Comment: Just opening in blender and re-exporting will not give you UV coordinates. You need to apply some. Sometimes there are semi-automatic ways of applying them using projections (cubic projection, spherical projection, cylindrical projection), but usually for a complex model you use a UV editor and it's a tedious process.

Comment: So, I tried a new one and I exported it form blender with the flag Include UVS, but for some reason it still does not have  any of those vt lines and it still won't work

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for some reason your messages don't popup until after I add a comment